# Fourier transform of the ln of a variable

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

Consider the following Fourier transform:
$$\hat{f}(\ln \xi) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) e^{-2\pi i x \ln{\xi}} \, \, dx $$
Assuming I can calculate $\hat{f}(\ln \xi)$, how can I go from $\hat{f}(\ln \xi)$ to $\hat{f}(\xi)$?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe substitute $\xi = e^u$? I mean, what exactly are you looking for here?

Comment: To avoid confusion, give it a different name! Let's call $\hat{g}(\zeta) = \int f(x) e^{-2\pi i x \ln \zeta}{\rm d}x$ and let's call the normal Fourier transform $\hat{f}(\zeta) = \int f(x) e^{-2\pi i x \zeta}{\rm d}x$. Then if you know $\hat{g}(\zeta)$ we have $\hat{f}(\zeta) = \hat{g}(e^{\zeta})$.